# Reducing point numbers in a certain area

Tags: c#, point, point-of-interest, simplify

We have a list of poi data in our database(Access mdb db), and we have a web service which serve data by a specified BoundingBox.

However we found that the returned points are too close to another at some area, so I wonder if it is possible to reducing the numbers of the points to make the result more even distributed.

Is this possible?

---

update:

Data schema:

```
id name address detail x y type
```

Where the `type` means if this point is a hotel or something else. We may take this field as the weight, for example, a point of `hotel` may have a high priority than that of a `untyped` point. So when reduce the number of the points, we may take this into account.

For our service, we get data like this:

```
http://server/ws?minx=10&maxx=20&miny=10&miny=20&size=50 //value of the parameter just for example
```

And the number of the items to be returned is specified by the paramter `size` from the client.

Please me know if further information is required.

Comment: On what basis would you like to remove them? Just at random?

Comment: It would be better if they can be removed according to some weight(from the field of the poi)

Comment: Could you add some more detail of the exact data structure / table schema you have (some representative data) to the question? Also, the exact logic would probably help, and the number of items you want in the bounding box.

Comment: @BradHards: I update my post, can you have a check?

Comment: Please add the exact logic for priority, and for the number of points to remove (absolute number to remove, absolute number to leave, proportion, or something else)

Comment: Ok, just remove points at random. For the number, I am not sure why this is necessary? Since the requirement is make the distribution as even as possible.